# operand evaluation order + assignment side effect

Tags: c

I want the following code to print 11, but prints 12, except in the last case, where it prints 10.

```
x=5; x1=x+(x=6); printf("%d\n",x1);  
x=5; x1=(x=x)+(x=6); printf("%d\n",x1);  
x=5; x1=(x+0)+(x=6); printf("%d\n",x1);  
x=5; x1=(x=5)+(x=6); printf("%d\n",x1);  

x=5; x1=(x=6)+x; printf("%d\n",x1);  
x=5; x1=(x=6)+(x=x); printf("%d\n",x1);  
x=5; x1=(x=6)+(x+0); printf("%d\n",x1);  
x=5; x1=(x=6)+(x=5); printf("%d\n",x1);
```

gcc says in every case: 'warning: operation on ‘x’ may be undefined'.

That's mean.

Bernhard

PS: There's no question, sorry. Thanks for your answers. :)
PPS: Actual code is:

```
while ( data-(data=read(adr)&(1<<6)) ) i++;
```

I'm waiting for bit 6 at adr to stop toggling.

Comment: Mutating a variable twice between sequence points is undefined behavior. So is mutating the variable, and then reading its value.

No matter what value you expect to get as a result, it is an invalid assumption. You should just rewrite the code to be standard-conformant.

Comment: Duplicate of [Could anyone explain these undefined behaviors (i = i++ + ++i , i = i++, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc)

Comment: The result is, as your compiler diagnosed, undefined. So don't write code like that.

Comment: Thanks Matthew for your link which made me read and understand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point and Pavels comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are undefined, no further explanation necessary. But to explain two possible ways the compiler *could* treat your code:

```
int x = 1;
int n = (x=3) + x;
```

The compiler can evaluate (x=3) first in which case the assignment to n has the value 6. Or it can evaluate x first, in which case the assignment to n has the value 4.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason for the warning...  The evaluation order between sequence points is unspecified.

Comment: Evaluation order between sequence points is *unspecified*. "Undefined" is a bit stronger term, and means that the standard doesn't specify anything about the behavior of any part of the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the little-used comma operator, along with another variable, in order to write the loop you wanted:

```
while ( lastdata = data, lastdata != (data = read(adr) & (1<<6)) ) i++;
```